# Perl CGI not running sql properly

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I am working on a basic registration page but I cannot seem to get the username check to trigger or the actual inserting into the db. In this page I take the info I pass in from my html page and first do a check to see if the username is already there. If not I redirect. Otherwise, I insert the values into the db and redirect to a new page. The output I get is this: 
[image: output]

I am not able to find what the actual issue is in my code..

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
#This is going to be the user login check and will set a cookie

use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; #Tells website to print content

use strict;

#Connection error 
sub showErrorMsgAndExit {
    print header(), start_html(-title=>shift);
    print (shift);
    print end_html();
    exit;
}

#Connecting to the database
my $dbUsername = "root";
my $dbPassword = "password";

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:f18final:localhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, {PrintError => 0});

#error checking
if(!$dbh) {
    print header(), start_html(-title=>"Error connecting to DB");
    print ("Unable to connec to the database");
    print end_html();
    exit;
}


print header;
print start_html(-title=>'Registration Page');

#Get the information the user entered
my $username = param('username');
my $password = param('password');
my $name = param('name');

#first sql check to see if username is already taken
my $check = "SELECT * from tblusers WHERE login = $username";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($check);
$sth->execute();
if($sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "<p>The user already exists. You will be redirected to register page in 5 seconds.</p>";
    print qq{<meta http-equiv="refresh" content = "5; url=/var/www/html/register.html"};
} else {
    #prepare to enter the content into the db
    my $sql  = "INSERT INTO tblusers(login, password, name) VALUES($username, $password, $name)";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    print "<p>Successfuly registered. You will be redirected to login in 5 seconds.</p>";
    print qq{<meta http-equiv="refresh" content = "5; url=/var/www/html/login.html"};
}


print end_html();
exit;
```

EDIT: A few more details for the post
I ran chmod on the register.cgi and did perl register.cgi and this was the output. 
[image]
The html file consists of only a form:

[image]

My sql table looks like this. (I added the first account manually in mysql workbench)
[image]

Comment: You print two CGI headers: `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`, and `print header`. The second one is treated as being part of the body.

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of that print statement. The actual content and the checks are still not working though.

Comment: And further down, you try to to add to the HTML header (`print qq{<meta http...}`) after you've already started the body.

Comment: What checks are not working?

Comment: It is still not inserting into the DB or checking if the user already exists

Comment: I mean, why do you claim that?

Comment: When I try to register with a username already in the db it skips directly to successfully registered. If I try to register a new account it tells me that it was successfully registered but when I check the db no content was added.

Comment: Don't describe, show. Also, if you think it's not working, check to see if an error was returned!

Comment: You've also have serious code injection bugs.

Comment: In fact, these are the source of your problem. Add error checking, and you'll find the problem.

Comment: You were right about the injection I believe. I managed to make it work now.

Comment: I hope you used `$dbh->quote` or placeholders. Adding quotes is not enough!

Comment: Please take a look at http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up ikegami’s comments in a single answer...

You have errors in your SQL queries. String variables need to be quoted when passed in the query. This will generate an error in the database, but you won’t see it because you did not set the RaiseError attribute on your handle, on top of which you disabled PrintError.

Enable error management when connecting the database :

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, {RaiseError => 1});
```

To avoid the quoting issue and at the same time protect your code against SQL injection, use bind parameters.

When looking up a user :

```
my $check = "SELECT * from tblusers WHERE login = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($check);
$sth->execute($username);
```

When creating a new user :

```
my $sql  = "INSERT INTO tblusers(login, password, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($username, $password, $name);
```